# Get feature installation cost prior to installation

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, burn, dtf

We're making a custom boostrapper / external UI for our installation.

We want to provide a "Custom Installation" dialog (like in MSI) to allow the user to choose feature(s) they want to install or remove.

Currently, we are able to read the features (and other feature details like description) from the MSI database itself (by running an SQL query on the `Feature` table).

However, we also want to display the cost of installing a feature. Windows Installer "Custom Installation" dialog is capable of doing this.

I think we can mimic the behavior by doing the following:

1. Pick a `Feature` that you want to get the cost
2. Using the `FeatureComponents` table, get the `Component` associated with the feature from 1
3. Using the `File` table, add the `FileSize` of the files associated with the component identified in 2
4. The sum from 3 is the cost of the feature installation

Question:

1. Is there an API (either from DTF or MSI.DLL) that we can use to get the cost of a feature PRIOR to installation? (There is a `FeatureInfo.GetCost` method in DTF but you can't use that directly. The product must be installed first before you can call `FeatureInfo.GetCost` from `ProductInstallation`)
2. If there is no API, is the procedure given above appropriate or correct to calculate the cost of a feature installation?

Thanks! :)

UPDATE # 1

I think there's a way to get the cost of a feature installation through the API even PRIOR to starting installation. Here's how I did it:

```cs
Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);

Session s = Installer.OpenPackage(@"C:\a.msi", false);

foreach (FeatureInfo info in s.Features)
{
    MessageBox.Show(info.Name);
    MessageBox.Show(info.GetCost(false, false, InstallState.Unknown).ToString());
}
s.Close();
```

calling `info.name` successfully returns the name of the feature. However, calling `info.GetCost` will return an `InvalidHandlerException` with a message: "selection manager not initialized".

Here's where I'm currently at.

Update #2:

I was getting the `InvalidHandlerException` because I am not invoking the needed [file costing routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before I call `info.GetCost`. Here's my modified code:

```cs
  Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);

  Session s = Installer.OpenPackage(@"C:\1.msi", false);
  s["ROOTDRIVE"] = @"C:\";
  s.DoAction("CostInitialize");
  s.DoAction("FileCost");
  s.DoAction("CostFinalize");

  foreach (FeatureInfo info in s.Features)
  {
       long cost = info.GetCost(false, false, InstallState.Local);
       MessageBox.Show(info.Title + " " + cost);
  }
  s.Close();
```

I am no longer getting the InvalidHandlerException but all file cost being returned is -1099511627776.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an API. You need to get an MSI Session by calling OpenPackage. By doing so, you will have access to the Feature list which will give you access to the GetCost method.

**1 Gotcha**: You need to perform 4 standard actions before calculating the cost: **CostInitialize**, **FileCost**, **CostFinalize** and **InstallValidate**.

```cs
    Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);

    Session s = Installer.OpenPackage(@"C:\1.msi", false);
    s.DoAction("CostInitialize");
    s.DoAction("FileCost");
    s.DoAction("CostFinalize");
    s.DoAction("InstallValidate");

    foreach (FeatureInfo info in s.Features)
    {
        long cost = info.GetCost(false, false, InstallState.Local);
        MessageBox.Show(info.Title + " " + cost);
    }
    s.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the answer you are looking for but I would suggest pre-calculating the sizes of the features at build time and using a precalculated table during install. This is what we do in [Burn](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/lets-talk-about-burn/) in WiX v3.6. It is **much** faster and **much** more stable.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what we ended up doing. The problem with the size was solved by calling s.DoAction("InstallValidate"). Pre-calculating makes the most sense because calling OpenPackage actually "launches" the engine (MSIEXEC) which maybe problematic on some scenarios and it also takes some time to calculate for the cost "interactively". Thanks for the suggestion! :)