# Wix Burn: Is ReserveCost suppressed in MsiPackage?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have a MSI file I built in  **Wix**, which uses a **ReserveCost** element in a Component to display the size of a feature which is mostly installed by a **CustomAction**.

When the MSI is executed by itself, the feature space required by this component shows up perfectly in the CustomizeDlg dialog, but when I include it in a **Burn bootstrapper bundle** the feature space shows a value which does not include the ReserveCost space.

Here's the **MsiPackage element**:

```xml
<MsiPackage Id="ARMDCore" Name="ARMDCore.msi" 
            SourceFile="..\ARMDCore\bin\Debug\ARMDCore.msi" 
            DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="no" 
            Cache="no" InstallSize="50000000" />
```

Here's the ReserveCost element:

```xml
<ReserveCost Id="ARMDPublicReserveCost" Directory="ARMDPUBLIC" 
             RunFromSource="16347877" RunLocal="16347877"/>
```

Any ideas on what causes this and the fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803189/get-feature-installation-cost-prior-to-installation

Comment: Thanks for the edits and suggestion Glytzhkof! I'll think about that technique but would still like to know what's going on with the ReserveCost element, that seems like the simple and intuitive approach and it makes little sense that it doesn't work right unless there's some bug in Burn.