# How WIX calculating required space to install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I had included msi in Bootstrapper project using MSiPackage under chain element.

I had observed Wix calculating required space using package size and Installed size, also observed Installed Size value is summation of all files size.

If I'm installing all the features present in msi then the summation of package Size and installed size was displaying in Control Panel as required space, which is correct.

But in my case, I'm not installing all the features. Even though only few features are installing, wix displaying entire package size and installed size in Control Panel.

Either all features were installed or only few features were installed, same space was displayed in Control Panel.

I'm using 3.11 version of wix and Visual Studio 2017.

I want to know exactly how wix calculating the required space to install and also, is wix calculating the space correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never looked at this. I see you have created a [WiX bug report](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6364). That's good. I found [this bug report too](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4039). I can verify that I too see MSI size reported in ARP change depending on what features are installed. MSI file size is calculated during [FileCosting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-costing) - as you no doubt have read. It does a lot of fancy calculations. [See Rob's answer here for Burn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4962492/129130) on file costig and sizes.

Comment: Could you set individual MSI files to show in ARP separately? The **Visible attribute** of the [MsiPackage element](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html). That should show the right sizes in ARP (Add / Remove Programs)?